# Dynamically match and replace using Bash

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using bash to dynamically find and replace a string with another string e.g.

```
href="/controller/action"

href="<?php echo $this->url("controller", action-> "action") ?>"
```

I'm using this sed command to find and change it which works fine...

```
sed -i 's%href=\"/controller/action%href=\"<?php echo $this->url(\"controller\", action-> \"action\") ?>%g' changes.txt
```

What I want is for the old string to look for any type following a pattern using a wildcard. I saw that this is an option but doesn't work.

```
sed -i 's%href=\"/(.*)/(.*)%href=\"<?php echo $this->url(\"/1\", action-> \"/2\") ?>%g' changes.txt
```

How will I be able to run this command so that the controller and action can be anything and dynamically taken from the old string and inputted into the new string?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Wrong output, no output, error message, core dump, something else? Imagine taking your car to the mechanic and the only clue you give them to the problem you want solved is "this car doesn't work".

Comment: Give this a shot: sed -i 's%href=\"/([^)]+)/([^)]+)%href=\"<?php echo $this->url(\"/1\", action-> \"/2\") ?>%g' changes.txt   I'm guessing the .* is messing is up.  You can change those to .*? if you feel like being lazy or what I have there.  If that works let me know and I'll write up a better answer.

Comment: Thanks sniperd I'll give that a shot! Some regex there oO. I'd like to try it with the not lazy version :P. Ed, no errors, no changing, no core dumps and no broken cars :)

Comment: @sniperd I gave that a go but it didn't change anything, unfortunately. No errors or anything just ran without change. Actually out of interest, is there an extra command that would give out a number of changes? Off the top of your head of course :)

Comment: Escape the capturing parentheses and use `[^/]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Hm, maybe I have a type-o in there.  I don't have sed (I'm in windows land) try it with .*?  instead of .*  and it might just work.  If the first one works, we are just trying to make the capture different.  .*? is basically a non-greedy way to capture up to the next thing, but it has some flaws (still usually does want you want)

Comment: Ah, replace (.*)  with \([^/]+\)  I think?

Comment: That and Wiktors worked for finding all those links and changed them! Is there a way to take what was the controller and action and input them into the new string. So say if it was /foo/bar the new string would be this-url('foo', action->'bar')? This would make amazing help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a greedy dot matching pattern the is almost never what you need since a dot matches any symbol and `*` quantifier grabs as many chars as it can. What you need is a negated bracket expression `[^/]*` matching zero or more chars other than `/`.

Also, since you are using a BRE POSIX regex you must escape the parentheses capturing a part of the pattern, else they denote literal `(` and `)` symbols.

Use

```
sed -i 's%href="/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)%href="<?php echo $this->url("\1", action-> "\2") ?>%g' changes.txt
```

Comment: I just managed to get it once you sent this. Didn't have the \(....\) and my values in the new string had /1 and /2 which was supposed to be \1 and \2. I know this is techniqually a different question but hoping you might be able to shed some light or resource to look into myself. The above works perfect. But there would be links that would be like /foo/bar?type=R&year=<?php echo $year;?>&batchNumber=<?php echo $this->escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?>"><?php echo $this->escapehtml($animal->BATCH_NUMBER);?> would would mess it up a bit. How would these be skipped?

Comment: @SmiffyKmc  Should that string  match?

Comment: @SmiffyKmc If it should not match, try `href="/\([^/<>]\+\)/\([^/?<>]\+\)\b\([^?]|$\)` and add `\3` at the end of the replacement string.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I haven't gotten around to trying that yet but doing so now. I did try to add the \3 at the end to see if it would do anything but the result wasn't great. Going to try your magic way!